Displaying Tagged Values in SysML Tables associated with Item Flows
I'm developing a Systems of Systems Model using SysML in CSM.  I want to show System A sending Data Item A to System B and then subsequently it outputting to a report or table with the tagged values of Data Item A.
I'm using System Blocks for the Systems and Blocks for the Data Items.  I've created a 'Data' stereotype that has properties of various Enumerations I created (Data Type, Data Standard, etc.)  When I apply this stereotype to the Blocks, i can go into the Specification and identify tagged values based on the enumerations embedded in the stereotype.
I have a high level BDD with the System to System item flows (I don't want to use dependencies, I want to show data flowing from one system to the other).  I can create an IBD for a specific System to System exchange.  In there I add a connector with an item flow and select Data Item A as the item i want to convey.  I then create a Whitebox ICD Table that i can customize to show Part A (System A), Item Flow (Data Item A) and Part B (System B).  So it shows what System A is sending Data Item A to System B.
Is it possible to show the tagged values within Data Item 1 (generated from the stereotype and enumerations) in the Whitebox ICD Table or another table?  My goal is to see System A sending Data Item to System B but also (in separate columns) showing the values for Data Type, Data Standard, etc. identified by the stereotype and enumeration.
I believe i can use flow ports or proxy ports with Interface blocks to do this by listing Data Type, Data Standard, Etc. as properties of the Flow port.  However, this seems duplicative since i already applied stereotypes.
